# How to chain pseudo selectors in SASS

Tags: css, haml, sass

I'm trying to put together a selector in SASS that will operate on the visted, hovered state of a link, but I can't quite seem to get the markup right, can someone enlighten me?
I was writing it like this:

```
 &:visited:hover
     attribute: foo
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
a
  &:visited:hover
    attribute: foo
```

Nowadays, this is the only valid form. Indention has to be consistent (2 spaces are recommended) and the colon follows the attribute.

Answer (score 1):

```
a
 &:visited:hover
    :attribute foo
```

Try that - note that identation is two spaces, and the colon goes before attribute not after.

Comment: I realise after coming back to this question after some time that it was indeed an indentation issue. This is sass after all :). Colon doesn't have to go before the attribute though, sass will accept either way of writing. I use the colon after as I find it easier to read.

Comment: "the colon goes before attribute not after" is not correct anymore

Comment: I'm learning SASS right now, and I stumbled over this page and noticed that this syntax (without curly braces, semicolons, etc.) doesn't seem to be available anymore? On http://sass-lang.com/tutorial.html, he syntax used is the "normal" CSS-syntax (except some more possibilities like encapsulation). Has this "old syntax" been dropped?

Comment: Yes. SCSS is better since its more like regular CSS and in fact can have straight CSS dropped into it

Comment: SCSS is not __better__ than SASS, just different. It all depends on how you are used to writing code. If you are used to HAML-style terseness, then you could argue that SASS is better (less lines of code, less syntax like braces, etc). Just pick your flavor and enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

Perfect for Hover and Before / After:

```
&:hover {
    color:#FFFFFF;

    &::before {
      color:#FFFFFF;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you reposting this answer?  The OP is not asking about SCSS syntax, they are asking about the indented SASS syntax.  Also, this code doesn't even compile.

Comment: the other scss dont work for me, my code works fine for me!